# Option Explicit - Label (Error Handler GoTo) not recognised

Tags: vba

I've made an UDF, pretty simple in a module with `Option Explicit` and I've got the error on the Label use as a target for Error Handling :

> Compilation error : Sub or Function not defined

Here is the code :

```
Public Function IsRowEmpty(ByVal aArray As Variant, ByVal RowNumber As Long) As Boolean
Dim j As Integer
    IsRowEmpty = True
    On Error GoTo ErrHdl:
    For j = LBound(aArray, 2) To UBound(aArray, 2)
        If aArray(RowNumber, j) <> "" Then
            IsRowEmpty = False
            Exit Function
        Else
        End If
    Next j
Exit Function
ErrHdl
    IsRowEmpty = False
End Function
```

I've looked around, but I can't seem to find a workaround...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing a `:` after the `ErrHdl` tag

```
Public Function IsRowEmpty(ByVal aArray As Variant, ByVal RowNumber As Long) As Boolean
    Dim j As Integer
    IsRowEmpty = True
    On Error GoTo ErrHdl
    For j = LBound(aArray, 2) To UBound(aArray, 2)
        If aArray(RowNumber, j) <> "" Then
            IsRowEmpty = False
            Exit Function
        Else
        End If
    Next j
Exit Function
ErrHdl:
    IsRowEmpty = False
End Function
```

Comment: Ohh my godness... I'd just misplaced my colon... What a rookie mistake!
Thx for pointing it out!